# String Error in asp.net when calling JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

HI guys I have a weird case here

I have a string declaration like you can see below

```
Dim a As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction("Testing");></script>"
```

here is my jquery. just a simple jquery
function myFunction(id){
$(id).dialog({
    modal: true, minWidth: 600, title: title
});

there the blue wavering line below `</script>`

it said on `</script>` that statement cannot appear within a method body. End of method assumed and it keep getting into like shown below whenever I move the cursor out of that one line

```
Dim a As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction("Testing");>"</script>"
```

I need this string to call my JQuery function

is it a bug from VS 2012 or what?

if you need more information about the code ask me. I will give more information.

Thanks for any help/suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the `"` in vb.

Try this:

```
Dim a As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction(""Testing"");></script>"
```

or if `Testing` is a variable:

```
Dim a As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction(" & Testing & ");></script>"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably, that your inner-quotes aren't escaped. So VB.Net is ending your String at myFunction("

Try escaping your inner double quotes by placing another double quote in front of them:

```
Dim a As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction(""Testing"");></script>"
```

**Edit**: Mikhail was faster and his answer assuming Testing is a variable seems to be more appropriate in this case:

```
Dim a As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction(" & Testing & ");></script>"
```